# Run some script after compiling code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

In my solution in VS 2022 I have several projects. One is a "vanilla" project type: library.

I want:

1. When clicking on the run (or debug) button
2. VS compiles the projects
3. And then runs my script. That script must (copy, but delete original) file `Vanilla.dll` to some target path

Comment: Solution Explorer => Project, right click => Properties => Section Build => Section Events => "Post-build events"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the thread related to [build-events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-events-page-project-designer-csharp?view=vs-2022).

For your problem, Fildor has a short solution.

Specifically, it can be implemented as follows (the example is the .Net Framework project, and the .Net project is the same):

Project—>Properties->Build->Post-build events

```
xcopy /y $(SolutionDir)1.txt $(ProjectDir) & del $(SolutionDir)1.txt
```

For the `macro address` in msbuild, you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(cs.ProjectPropertiesBuildEventsBuilder)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2022).

The example first uses `xcopy` to copy the file to the specified address, and then uses `del` to delete the file at the original address.

[image]