# I have a C# dll that I am using in several C# projects. If I update the dll I have to rebuild all the projects manualy. How can I automate this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, dll, build

I have a C# dll (VS 2022) that I am using in several C# projects (VS 2022). If I update the dll I have to rebuild all the related projects manually.

1. Is it possible to program something in the dll that when I build it, all the related projects are built automatically
2. If 1) is not possible, can I make this automation with a separate C# project or powershell script?

Comment: 1. NO.  2) Yes ..

Comment: You could create a Solution, add your dll project, and all of your projects that depend on this dll. Then right click each project and select "Project dependencies".

Comment: You can use the command line compiler csc.exe.  See following : https://tomasvera.com/programming/compiling-a-c-project-using-command-line-tools-tutorial?force_isolation=true

Comment: why do you need to compile all other dependent projects? If the signatures or interfaces are not containing breaking changes, simply point to the new updated dll or copy it.
You may adjust the versioning in the dependend projects, to be satisfied with certain major versions

Comment: Isn't this what you call automation? As long as you do this, you don't need to manually modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Visual Studio and assuming all the source code for the DLL and the consumers of the DLL is in the same source control repo:

- Create a solution (.sln)
- Add all the projects to the solution, including the DLL project and the projects that depend on the DLL
- In the projects that depend on the DLL, add a project reference to the DLL project

Building the solution or building a specific project within the solution will check dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I tested two methods

Put the Dll project and the Dll-dependent project into a solution, add [Build Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ProjectDependenciesDlg)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2022). This ensures that when compiling dependent projects, the dependent projects are compiled first.

What you need is as Jonathan said: add [project references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022#add-a-reference), which can automatically update the current project when compiling the referenced project.

There is another way: if the way you add references is by using [browse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022#browse). For example, put the dll in a folder and import it into the project.

You can add a [post-build event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75540007/16764901) to your dll project:

```
del $(SolutionDir)ConsoleApp1\ClassLibrary1.dll & xcopy /y $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)ConsoleApp1\
```

After you build the dll, you can automatically update the dll of the target address.